# Switch between themes in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, themes, application-switcher

I installed Mint and Ubuntu MATE themes to my computer.

Ubuntu MATE was my final theme installation.

Now I have Ubuntu MATE on my computer. 
But I want to switch into Mint theme.

The log in screen used to let me to change the theme, but now there is no button for it.
I think Ubuntu Mate doesn't support that button, and I'm stuck in the Mate Theme.

Can someone tell me how to switch between themes? It's better if the solution is through the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Menu**  -  **System Settings**  -  **Appearance** - **Themes** and choose the theme.

If you want to call login screen press **Ctlr+ Alt + Del**.

Answer (score 0):

Download `Unity Tweak Tool` (`sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`)  and it will allow you to change themes, as well as mix themes and window button appearance